# Nest.js is giving cors error when i put my app online

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cors, nestjs

I'm developing a Nest.js - React.js app. Now, I am having cors error even when I have cors enabled in my main.ts file of nest.js.

My app works on localhost and also on ip-address in production but when it accessed from the internet it return a cors error:

> (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Here's my main.ts file.

```
app.enableCors({
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    const allowedOrigins = [
      'http://localhost:5173',
      'http://my.ip.address:5173',
      'http://my.online.app.url:5173',
      'http://my.online.app.url:5173',
    ];

    if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, origin);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: ['content-type'],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
});
```

And this is the error:

[image: error]

I tried:

```
app.enableCors({
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
});
```

and also:

```
app.enableCors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
});
```

and also:

```
app.enableCors({
  origin: 'http://my.online.app.url:5173',
  credentials: true,
});
```

And all of this didn't work !!!

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant client code. Your client may include request headers (such as `Authorization`) that are currently disallowed in your CORS configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.enableCors({
  origin: 'http://my.online.app.url:5173',
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
});
```

Make sure to allow the required request headers in the CORS configuration. If your client application includes special headers such as `Authorization` you need to explicitly allow them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get CORS error if You are requesting with http protocol and server makes redirect to https.
Check if you have configured redirect from http to https. Or just change api url to https:// for server